# Symfony 4 error rendering form even though I have createview()?

Tags: php, symfony4

I'm REALLY new to Symfony 4 but I've been following the guide [here](https://codereviewvideos.com/course/symfony-4-beginners-tutorial/video/symfony-4-contact-form) to make a form.  I followed along exactly as in the video but for whatever reason I get the error

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::renderBlock() must be an instance
>   of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, string given

and it highlights the line

> 'search_form' => $form->createView(),

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out as everything just says I need to do the createView()...but I'm doing that.  What am I missing?  Code below:

PatientSearchController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Form\PatientSearchType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class PatientSearchController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/patient/search", name="patient_search")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(PatientSearchType::class);

        return $this->render('patient_search/index.html.twig', [
            'search_form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

patient_search/index.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    {{ form_start('search_form') }}
    {{ form_widget('search_form') }}
    {{ form_end('search_form') }}
{% endblock %}
```

PatientSearchType:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Patients;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PatientSearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('PatientId')
            ->add('Address1')
            ->add('Address2')
            ->add('City')
            ->add('State')
            ->add('Phone1')
            ->add('Phone2')
            ->add('Email')
            ->add('DateOfBirth')
            ->add('InsuranceId')
            ->add('InsuranceNo')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Patients::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: As the error states, the twig form methods are looking for the object variable, not a string. `{{ form_start(search_form) }}` See: [How to Customize Form Rendering](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-rendering-basics)

Comment: Ah I knew it had to be some stupid I missed like that.  That worked - thanks so much!